# Graphviz - Squished on page and rank not respected

Tags: configuration, graphviz, dot, image-size

[enter image description here][1]I'm just learning GraphViz and I'm struggling with some Basic issues. I have two subgraphs that should be able to show basic nodes and links between, see code:

```
digraph G {
graph [rankdir="TB", splines=ortho, nodesep=2, ranksep=2.5, fontsize=18, fontname="Verdana"];
node [shape=record, height=3, width=3];
rankdir = TB;


subgraph cluster_0 {    
    node [style=filled, color=lightgrey, fontsize=18, fontname="Verdana"];
    label = "DMZ 1";
    PWI -> PWE -> PWI
}

subgraph cluster_1 {
    node [style=filled, color=lightgrey, fontsize=18, fontname="Verdana"];
    label = "Trusted Zone EBC" ;
    PR1 -> PWI [headlabel="test text", labeldistance=2.5] 
    PWI -> PR1  
    PR1 -> PWE  
    PWE -> PR1  
    PWI -> PWE -> PWI  
    PFI -> PWE  
    PFI -> PWI  
    PWE -> PFI  
    PWI -> PFI  
    PBW -> PWI  
    PBW -> PWE  
    PWI -> PBW  
    PWE -> PBW  
    PSM -> PWE  
    PSM -> PWI  
    PWE -> PSM  
    PWI -> PSM  
    {rank = same; PR1; PFI; PSM; PBW}
    {rank = same; PWI}
    {rank = same; PWE}
}
```

}

Which leads to the below.. Am I hitting the edges of [enter image description here][2]a "canvas" if so, can I increase it? And why are the ranks not being respected where the top rank is being shown on the same as the lowest rank, as well as the middle rank being above them?

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/meU6p.png

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not hitting the edges of the "canvas", because the default is to expand it to fit your graph.

The problem with ranks in your graph is that you have edges going in both directions between the nodes. Since Graphviz considers the left side of an edge to have higher rank than the right side, all those edges confuses Graphviz.

If you instead always create edges *from a higher* ranked (according to what you want) node *to a lower* ranked node and use the [dir](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:dir) attribute to specify that the edge should point in the backwards direction like so: `n1 -> n2 [dir=back]`, Graphviz will get a consistent perception of the node ranks and respect your intended ranks.

Perhaps this is more in line with what you want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.2/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@2.4.2/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

var dotSrc = `
digraph G {
graph [rankdir="TB", splines=ortho, nodesep=2, ranksep=2.5, fontsize=18, fontname="Verdana"];
node [shape=record, height=3, width=3];
rankdir = TB;


subgraph cluster_0 {    
    node [style=filled, color=lightgrey, fontsize=18, fontname="Verdana"];
    label = "DMZ 1";
    PWE -> PWI
    PWE -> PWI [dir=back]
}

subgraph cluster_1 {
    node [style=filled, color=lightgrey, fontsize=18, fontname="Verdana"];
    label = "Trusted Zone EBC" ;
    PWI -> PR1 [headlabel="test text", labeldistance=2.5 dir=back] 
    PWI -> PR1  
    PWE -> PR1 [dir=back]
    PWE -> PR1  
    PWE -> PWI [dir=back]
    PWE -> PWI  
    PWE -> PFI [dir=back]
    PFI -> PWI  
    PWE -> PFI  
    PFI -> PWI [dir=back]
    PWI -> PBW [dir=back]   
    PWE -> PBW [dir=back]
    PWI -> PBW  
    PWE -> PBW  
    PWE -> PSM [dir=back]
    PWI -> PSM [dir=back]
    PWE -> PSM  
    PWI -> PSM  
    {rank = same; PR1; PFI; PSM; PBW}
    {rank = same; PWI}
    {rank = same; PWE}
}
}
`;

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
  .renderDot(dotSrc);

</script>
```